# Executing script when SQL query is executed

Tags: php, python, mysql, database

I want to execute script(probably written in python), when update query is executed on MySQL database. The query is going to be executed from external system written in PHP to which I don't have access, so I can't edit the source code. The MySQL server is installed on our machine. Any ideas how I can accomplish this, or is it even possible?

Comment: What python script is suppose to do?

Comment: Does that external system returns you a response? whether the execution is success or not?

Comment: could you simply check periodically if the data was altered in your pyhton script?

Comment: Dinesh Pundket - The python script is going to take the data and put it in another database.
masterFly - no it doesn't
user18... - Yes that's what I'm going to do but the period must be short so I wanted to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to call external scripts from MySQL.

The only thing you can do is adding an ON UPDATE trigger that will write into some queue. Then you will have the python script POLLING the queue and doing whatever it's supposed to do with the rows it finds.